# How should one get married if they have committed sexual immoralities?

Tags: fiqh, nikah, sex, zina

I am a muslim male. When I was a child a person older than me had anal sex with me several times.
When I was a teenager I had oral sex with one of my cousins. Does that make me a fornicator? According to Quran 24:3 A fornicator does not marry except a fornicator. How can I get married?

Answer (score 0):

You repent and reform your ways. Then you will no longer be considered a fornicator.

> التائب من الذنب كمن لا ذنب له
>
> The one who repents from sin is like one who did not sin.
>
> <sup>— [Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:4250) -  classed as hassan or sahih based on [corroboration](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/182767/)</sup>

> أن رجلا أراد أن يزوج ابنة، فقالت: إني أخشى أن أفضحك، إني قد بغيت، فأتى عمر فقال: أليست قد تابت؟ قال: نعم قال: فزوجها
>
> A man decide to marry off his daughter. She said: I fear I will bring shame to you, for I have committed fornication. He came to Umar.
>
> Umar asked: Has she not repented?
>
> He said: Yes
>
> Umar said: Then marry her off.
>
> <sup>— [Musannaf Ibn Abi Shaybah](https://shamela.ws/book/333/20312#p1)</sup>

The majority considers it permissible for a fornicator to marry anyone. Especially after repentance. The verse 24:3 is interpreted as follows:

- The verse is from the time when marriage with non-muslims was permissible. The verse made it forbidden for Muslims to marry non-muslim prostitutes. And later it was made forbidden to marry all non-muslims ([2:221](https://quran.com/2/221?translations=20), [60:10](https://quran.com/60/10?translations=20)). The prohibition does not apply to Muslim sinners as they are included in the permission granted by the verses:

  > وأنكحوا الأيامى منكم
  >
  > And marry the unmarried among you
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 24:32](https://quran.com/24/32?translations=20)</sup>

  > وأحل لكم ما وراء ذلكم
  >
  > And lawful to you are [all others] beyond these
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 4:24](http://quran.com/4/24)</sup>
- ينكح here means sex (fornication) not marriage. The verse is news rather than a ruling. It is simply says that a fornicator fornicates with a fornicatress or a polytheist. It is a condemnation and prohibition of fornication, not a ruling on legal marriage.
- Some hold that it forbids marriage by fornicators to anyone, but that restriction is removed by repentance.
- A minority holds that a person who has been convicted and punished under the Hadd for Zina can only marry another person who too has been convicted and punished.